# Adding natural docs style remarks generation to the intellij idea

Tags: coding-style, intellij-idea, documentation-generation

I'm looking for a way to add [natural-docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) style remark generation to the intellij IDEA.
In a way similar to how javadoc remarks are being generated.
I tried the "Settings" -> "Code Style" menu but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Natural Docs Example:

```
/*
   Function: Multiply

   Multiplies two integers.

   Parameters:

      x - The first integer.
      y - The second integer.

   Returns:

      The two integers multiplied together.

   See Also:

      <Divide>
*/
int Multiply (int x, int y)
   {  return x * y;  };
```

Comment: Can you clarify it with a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

IDEA can generate only JavaDoc standard stubs for your methods when you type `/**` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It knows nothing about natural docs. To support such docs generation you'd need to write a plug-in or [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) so that it's considered by IDEA developers.

Comment: That's What I thought, but I kinda hoped someone will come out with a better answer.